# Not always sometime getting the "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." Error in Django web application

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-csrf

I have one login form in Django template as given below:-

```
<form action="{% url 'doLogin' %}" class="form-group" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- <span class="fa fa-lock"></span> -->
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>
```

The view Functions are defined as given below:-

```
def loginUser(request):
    return render(request, 'login_page.html')
```

```
def doLogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Login Credentials!! Remember Username and Password are case sensitive!!!')
            return render(request, 'login_page.html')
```

In settings.py file I have included following parameters with value given below:-

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['gyanbharatimau.co.in']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://gyanbharatimau.co.in']
```

Now its working fine in development as well as in production environment. But sometime in production environment (Not always I guess 2 or 3 times daily) login attempt is failing with following error message:-

```
Forbidden (403)
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

When i enabled the debug in production i am getting following details:-

```
Help
Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token from POST incorrect.
    
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly
```

Now i want to know that Is there something I am missing in the code or it is happening because of genuine Cross Site Request Forgery.

Thanks & Regards
Neha Singh

I tried searching for similar issues on the Stackoverflow website. There are some information but I think my code is already having all that pieces. Please let me know what to do to fix this issue.

Comment: Please help me on this. I am stuck on this and could not get the actual reason of getting the error.